# ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type : What is error in this code?

Tags: java, arraylist

I was creating an ArrayList, and i am getting following error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type
Please help.

```
package learnCoreJava;

import java.util.List;

public class ArrayListDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Always initialize the concrete implementation with the interface types
                List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(5);
                
                for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
                    arrayList.add(i);
                
                System.out.println(arrayList);
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to `import java.util.ArrayList` as well.

Comment: If you are using an IDE like eclipse or intellij, you should check your IDE's suggestions. Surely there are wiggly lines near the ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

Add this import statement :-

`import java.util.ArrayList;`